How to Make Parallel Requests for the Same Text Using Different Variables
I’m a beginner with LangChain, and I’m working on a project that requires making parallel requests to process the same input text across multiple categories. Here’s the challenge: each category needs a different set of examples to guide the output generation.
Here’s what I’m trying to achieve:
I have a single input text that needs to be processed.
For each category (e.g., "medications," "family history," "exams"), I have a unique prompt and a specific set of examples.
I want to execute these requests in parallel to improve efficiency.
I’m new to LangChain, so any help or suggestions (even simple ones!) would be highly appreciated.

chains = {}
inputs = {}
for category, content in prompts.get("medical_queries", {}).items():
    try:
        prompt_content = content["prompt"]
        prompt_examples = content["examples"]

        prompt_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(prompt_content)

        chains[category] = LLMChain(prompt=prompt_template, llm=llm)

        inputs[category] = {"input": text, "example": content["examples"]}
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{category}: {e}")

pipeline = RunnableParallel(chains)

responses = pipeline.invoke(inputs)

I’m using RunnableParallel, but I’m struggling to figure out the best way to handle the examples dynamically for each category.
What I’ve tried so far:
Passing examples dynamically during the request.
Formatting prompts by embedding examples beforehand. However, I either encounter issues with missing inputs variables.
